AVAudioEngine: compensate latency between 2 AVAudioMixerNode inputs
Context:
I have an AVAudioMixerNode accepting 2 inputs:

input A: an AVAudioUnitSampler (triggered by a MIDI track of an AVAudioSequencer);
input B: an AVAudioPlayerNode.

All nodes are connected to the same AVAudioEngine instance.
Inputs of the AVAudioMixerNode are in perfect sync. But inserting an AVAudioUnitTimePitch between the player and the mixer adds about 93 ms delay to input B.
Question:
Is there a portable way to adjust delays so that inputs A and B of the mixer are in sync?
Current solution:
My current workaround is to insert an AVAudioUnitTimePitch at the output of the sampler in order to add a similar delay to input A. This approximately works with my current device (there's only a 5 ms delay instead of the initial 90 ms), but AFAIK I'm not guaranteed that that both delays will always compensate (during execution or across devices).

Look at the latency of your nodes, you should be able to figure out how much of it you need to add to your player node B. After that, I'm not sure - an AVAudioUnitDelay with feedback = -100? An AVAudioSinkNode and an AVAudioSourceNode to manually delay the samples?
